# Difficulty in finding volume of the swimming pool

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume

A rectangular swimming pool is 50 meters long and 25 meters wide. Its depth is always the same along its width but linearly increases along its length from 1 meter at one end to 4 meters at the other end. How much water (in cubic meters) is needed to completely fill the pool?

---

I am not able to visualize the swimming pool as described.  What exactly is meant by depth remaining same along the width ? how is that measured ?

[image]

Depth along the length should be like this i guess, but now how to incorporate depth along the width ?

Comment: Note that the average depth is $\dfrac{1+4}2 $meters $=2.5 $ meters

Comment: How is the the depth being measured along the length and along the width, can you show it through a diagram please  ?

Comment: Draw a diagram yourself, what would a cross section look like if drawn from the 50m side of the pool?

Comment: a trapezium with two parallel sides of lengths 1 m and 4 m . with the distance between the 2 parallel sides equal to 50 m, but I believe we have only taken into account depth along the length ? How to also consider the depth measured along width ?

Comment: It means that the bottom depth is constant along a line perpendicular to the 50m length. So the volume will be given by $25A$ where $A$ is the area of the shape you have drawn (which is a triangle and a rectangle).

Comment: what do you mean by bottom depth ? thats the depth measured along the length only right referring to how deep the pool is ?

Comment: The pool has two ends $50$ meters apart, shown at the left and right ends of your diagram. It has two sides $25$ meters apart. One side of the pool is in the exact same shape as your figure. So is the other side. So is a lengthwise cross-section of the pool halfway between the sides, or at any distance from either side. The fact that it's the same cross-section on both sides and also at any distance between the sides is what the problem awkwardly asserts with the words "always the same along its width".

Answer (score 3):

The shape is a trough. Imagine that the shape you drew is a cross section of the trough. Practically, this means that the volume will be $25\times A$ where $A$ is the area of the drawn figure.

To get the area we can fill in the missing triangle in the diagram, calculate the area of the resulting rectangle and then subtract the area of the triangle that we added to get the value of $A$.

Filling in the triangle gives $A+\text{ area of triangle}=4\times 50=200$

The triangle has height $3$ and base $50$ so its area is $75$.

Therefore, the area of the trapezoid in the diagram is $200-75=125$ and the volume of the trough is $25\times 125=3125$.